# How is this an Even function?

Tags: functions

How is this,

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} |x + 1|, \quad &-2 \le x \le 0 \\
|x - 1|, \quad& 0 < x \le 2
\end{array}\right.$$

an **even** function?

Comment: You should break the absolute values up into cases.

Comment: Here's its graph: W

Comment: Though not a proof, it is often useful to imagine the graphs of these functions in your head and note the invariance after reflection about the y-axis.

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts in 
this and future posts. Formatting tips 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x>0$, then
\begin{align*}
f(-x) & = |-x+1| && (\because -x <0 \text{ we use the first part of the function})\\
& = |(x-1)(-1)|\\
&=|x-1|\\
&=f(x).
\end{align*}
Similarly prove it for the case when $x<0$.

Comment: Why do you need to look at $x<0$?

Answer (score 1):

For $-2< x < 0$, we have
$$f(x) = |x + 1| = |-(x+1)| = |-x-1| = f(-x).$$